# Counting numerical semigroups by largest element of minimal generating set

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, co.combinatorics

For a given integer $n$, I am interested in the number of different numerical semigroups one can make with a generating set consisting only of integers in $[n]$.

I have done some small examples. For $n=1$ there is only $\langle 1\rangle$ and the same goes for $n=2$. For $n=3$ there are only $\langle 1\rangle$ and $\langle 2,3\rangle$ and for $n=4$ there are $\langle 1\rangle$, $\langle 2,3\rangle$, and $\langle 3,4\rangle$. For $n=5$ I won't list all the ones I found but I believe there to be $7$ of them, and for $n=6$ I found $8$ (of course I may have made a mistake).

I have found references online counting numerical subgroups by multiplicity $m$ and genus $g$, but was not able to find anything on this variant of the counting problem. In fact, it would be *really* great if I could figure out how to count the number of numerical semigroups with generating set in $[n]$ and with genus $g$, for given integers $n$ and $g$. Any remarks or pointers to the literature would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi! The binary operation is $+$ here. So, for instance, $\langle 2,3\rangle = {\bf N}\setminus \{1\}$. Sorry, I should have specified.

Comment: $\langle3,4\rangle$ is generated by integers in $[3]$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson sorry, off-by-one error, will correct.

Comment: For $n=6$ I get $9$, not $8$.

Comment: Aren't there two semigroups for $n=2$: $\mathbb N$ and $2\mathbb N$ ?

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev It seems the definition often includes having a finite complement, so I suspect that's why $2\mathbb{N}$ is not allowed.

Comment: For $n=6$, I get 1, 23, 25, 34, 345, 35, 45, 456, 56, agreeing with Richard.

Comment: Ok, then the sequence is$$1, 1, 2, 3, 7, 9, 19, 27, 46, 63, 113, 148, 253, 345, 539, 734, \dots$$ via quick'n'dirty [Sage code](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJx1UdEKwjAMfBf8hzy2KGXrozB_Yl-gW1YLkpauQ_TrTapDnXpvvV4uuaTHAUanSO_WK2C00MCIWenHcwgJHHiCdjoyPSpVG0N6Vgv8AGck5XTTVG-0oAuUPU34YnP99HfadCFe5z7lz372FlxO_oxctTBGVubaxBDfxQ8Tc-h7hQtacqCVINkuvASR_XCD9vuH08U9AZfHv9W_o74il4mi_liZ63qVLe9sGa0tahhSuCHJNlgFz9qEeUpU1t0ytV5JLJK55Cy2ms8Sk6esaFsOq-9rt2jz&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) for these counts for small $n$. 

If we don't enforce finite complement, it would be https://oeis.org/A103580

Comment: @RichardStanley ah yes, I believe I missed $\langle 4,5,6\rangle$, apologies!

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev Forgive me if this is obvious, but how does the code work? I am trying to figure out how the semigroups are enumerated in the code but have gotten a bit lost. I was thinking/hoping there would be an inductive formula, but given that the code you posted is not recursive, it's not so clear that's the case I guess!

Comment: @MarcelK.Goh: I've added explanation as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A key observation is that two sets of generators $g, g'\subseteq [n]$ produce the same semigroup if and only if $\langle g\rangle \cap [n] = \langle g'\rangle \cap [n]$. Hence, the number of different semigroups equals the number of different $\langle g\rangle \cap [n]$ for $g\subseteq [n]$ (and this is what is computed in a naive way by the Sage code that I shared in the comments).

The question has an implicit restriction that the complement of $\langle g\rangle$ must be finite, which is equivalent to $g$ being set-wise coprime. Let's refer to the semigroups under this restriction as *primitive* and denote their number as $P(n)$. Without this restriction the semigroups (ie. both primitive and non-primitive) are enumerated by [OEIS A103580](https://oeis.org/A103580). It is easy to see the following connection between the two counts:
$${\tt A103580}(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n P(\lfloor \tfrac{n}{k}\rfloor ),$$
which implies that $P(n)$ can be obtained via [Möbius inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula#Generalizations):
$$P(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n \mu(k)\cdot {\tt A103580}(\lfloor \tfrac{n}{k}\rfloor ).$$
From 100 terms provided in the OEIS for A103580, we can immediately obtain $P(n)$ for $n\leq 100$.

Efficient computation of A103580 is discussed in the paper [Counting numerical semigroups by Frobenius number, multiplicity, and depth](https://arxiv.org/abs/2208.14587) by Sean Li (see Remark on page 12).

*PS.* I've added $P(n)$ to the OEIS as [sequence A358392](https://oeis.org/A358392).